# An error when I write apt update in the terminal

Tags: debian, apt, repository, latex

This question is about an error of a sign of MikTeX in my computer with Debian. This error is

```
E: El repositorio «http://miktex.org/download/debian stretch InRelease» no está firmado.
```

This means that:

```
The repository «http://miktex.org/download/debian stretch InRelease» is not signed.
```

when I write `apt update` in the terminal. I don't know why this happens. Is this normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you've already added it to `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

You then need to register the GPG key for the MikTeX repo:

First, install `dirmngr` if you haven't already:

```
apt-get install dirmngr
```

The register the key:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys D6BC243565B2087BC3F897C9277A7293F59E4889
```

After that,

```
apt-get update
apt-cache policy
```

The second command should show you the URL for the MikTeX repo.

After that,

```
apt-get install miktex
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Why does this work?

Comment: @Elborito The repo has to have a signed key to verify the authenticity very much in the same way that a website using `https` has to have a certificate signed by a certificate authority. It's to verify its legitimacy in order to make sure that it isn't engaging in any kind of dubious activity.